# Android classes not working

Tags: android, database

I am trying to run a class that will check for information in a data base then display it on the screen. it was working yesterday untill i added in code for it to check information in a second table i will post both the code and the logcat as i dont know why this is happening

```
public class WorkoutProgress extends ListActivity {

  private DataBaseHelper datasource;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.progress);

    datasource = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    datasource.open();
    fillData();
    datasource.close();
  }
  private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
    Cursor c = datasource.getAllTitles();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] {DataBaseHelper.KEY_CODE,  DataBaseHelper.KEY_DAYS,DataBaseHelper.KEY_BMI };
    int[] to = { R.id.code, R.id.Days, R.id.BMI };
    String[] from2 = new String[] {DataBaseHelper.KEY_DATE,  DataBaseHelper.KEY_STEPS,DataBaseHelper.KEY_CALs };
    int[] to2 = { R.id.date, R.id.steps, R.id.cals };
    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
     new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes2 =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from2, to2);
    setListAdapter(notes);
  }

  public void add(View view) {
    //Do nothing
  }

  public void delete(View view) {
     datasource.open();
     datasource.deleteFirst();
     fillData();
     datasource.close();
  }
}
```

and the log cat when i try to access this class is

```
04-06 01:10:42.293: E/global(22219): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
04-06 01:10:42.293: E/global(22219):    at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
04-06 01:10:42.293: E/global(22219):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1391)
04-06 01:10:42.293: E/global(22219):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1356)
04-06 01:10:42.293: E/global(22219):    at com.b00348312.workout.Splashscreen$1.run(Splashscreen.java:42)
04-06 01:10:45.393: I/Database(22219): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
04-06 01:10:45.393: E/Database(22219): Failure 1 (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) on 0x2c0e38 when preparing 'create table goals (_id primary key autoincrement, code text not null,days title text not null, bmi text not null);'.
04-06 01:10:45.403: D/AndroidRuntime(22219): Shutting down VM
04-06 01:10:45.403: W/dalvikvm(22219): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
04-06 01:10:45.453: D/dalvikvm(22219): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4012 objects / 253248 bytes in 32ms
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.b00348312.workout/com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutProgress}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: create table goals (_id primary key autoincrement, code text not null,days title text not null, bmi text not null);
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: create table goals (_id primary key autoincrement, code text not null,days title text not null, bmi text not null);
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1817)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at com.b00348312.workout.DataBaseHelper$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DataBaseHelper.java:59)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at com.b00348312.workout.DataBaseHelper.open(DataBaseHelper.java:78)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutProgress.onCreate(WorkoutProgress.java:21)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
04-06 01:10:45.453: E/AndroidRuntime(22219):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace says:

> Failure 1 (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) on
>   0x2c0e38 when preparing 'create table goals (_id primary key
>   autoincrement, code text not null,days title text not null, bmi text
>   not null);'.

It looks like you forgot to declare the `_id` field as an `INTEGER` in your `create table` statement.

Comment: +1. I really wish new programmers would learn to actually **read** error messages, instead of just "My code doesn't work. Here's the error message. What's wrong?" This one is really clear.

Comment: @ Ken white, sorry but I'm not well versed in logcat just yet. Ihave only really begun to use it and i was not sure what errors I should be looking out for. now after implementing these changes I still have a problem but its saying that there is no column when I have clearly defined it/

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that your DataBaseHelper did not specify the type of column `_ID` on database creation. You have to define it as `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started Android programming and I use the USB debugging to try out my apps. I realized that after a possible SQL failure, the database isn't erased from your device the next time you run it, and any changes you make don't take effect.

So say your "create table" SQL statement was wrong in some way. Your program crashes. You find the problem and fix it. If you run your program again, the same old database is used unless you increase the version.

So go to your device and uninstall the program, then run it again from your computer. This time I think the database will be created all over again using your fresh "create table" SQL.

Since I'm new, this might not be what is happening and I'm open to correction if that's so.